# MuMIn model.sel error with glmmTMB models

Tags: r, mumin

When I apply `model.sel` function to `g0` model below, it runs fine. However when I create similar models using my data, I get the error as shown below. Any clues in why I could be getting this error?

```
data(sleepstudy,package="lme4")
g0 <- glmmTMB(Reaction~Days+(Days|Subject),sleepstudy)
model.sel(g0)
```

The above runs fine, however, this doesn't:

Data location: https://mqoutlook-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/joseph_mbui_mq_edu_au/EjFIajIJxxxBsIBcMi3GyIMBc6FyN4a5y-39cDev2Aoyng?e=tUTj2W

```
datT<-read.csv('datT.csv')
myModel<-glmmTMB(y~x1+x2+ (1|randomEffect),list(family="beta",link="logit"), data=datT)
model.sel(myModel)
Error in vapply(unique(f), function(x) if (is.na(x)) NA_character_ else formals(get(x))$link,  : 
values must be length 1,
but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 0
```

The only difference between the two configurations is that I am fitting `beta` family

I have tried switching `na.options` and have installed the latest versions of the associated packages.

Comment: Could be a bug. Can you give a reproducible example?

Comment: This has now ben updated with a reproducible example

Comment: @KamilBartoń this has now been updated with a a reproducible example

Comment: The data file under the link is not accessible for non-users.

Comment: @KamilBartoń link is now accessible to non-users

Comment: Not really. It still asks me to log in.

Comment: looks good to me..please try again

Comment: Here is a new error that I get with `model.sel`: `Error in if (REML) { : argument is of length zero`

Answer (score 2):

This was caused by the unusual `family` formulation by `glmmTMB`. It is fixed now in `MuMIn` 1.40.7 on R-Forge: `install.packages("MuMIn", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")`

Comment: Here is a new error that I get with `model.sel`: `Error in if (REML) { : argument is of length zero`

Comment: This error does not seem to come from any of MuMIn's functions. Run a `traceback()` after the error.

Comment: For me, I was using `summary` on glmmTMB objects and getting `Error in if (REML) { : argument is of length zero`.  I was loading in saved objects that were run under R < 3.5 into R 3.5.  I reran the models and saved the objects under R 3.5 and the error was resolved.  FWIW.